# Can't use Bootcamp partition for Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I'm trying to install Windows 8 with Bootcamp on my Macbook Pro.
Sadly it won't let me get past the disk partition choice (even after formatting the Bootcamp-drive).

It says:

> Windows can't be installed on this storage device. The chosen harddisk contains a MBR-partition-table. Windows can only be installed on GPT-harddisks on EFI-systems. *freely translated*

What is going wrong here?

Here's a photo:

[image]

Comment: What you select: `EFI boot` or `USB drive with windows files` on the start screen?

Comment: I select partition 4.

Comment: No, on the grey start screen, when you reboot your pc and hold the option key to select the boot source. When I'd boot in EFI mode, installator said me the same thing, so I'd boot from the USB flash drive itself and it worked for me.